# is this a valid delete operation in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a `vector<some_struct&> array` in my code, and whenever I want to add some object to my vector I use `array.push_back(*new some_struct)`. now I'm wondering if I should delete every object in my array before clearing my array (using delete &array[i]) or not?

Comment: -1 stated existing code `vector<some_struct&>` is not possible.

Comment: @Alf : To be clear, it's possible (provided your compiler is willing to compile it without complaint), but it's UB.

Comment: @Alf, +1 to equalized your downvote. If OP's compiler is accepting `vector<some_struct&>` then question is perfectly valid. IMO, this is not worth a downvote.

Comment: @iammilind: you can't form a raw array of references, and you can't form a pointer to reference. but a vector contains a (pointer to first element of) raw array. therefore i can't see any way a compiler can accept the OP's alleged code. unless **[leprechauns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor#Testing_the_razor)** are involved.

Comment: You are fussing about this using rather esoteric arguments around UB and compiler features when actually the poster hasn't understood the basic principles of what he is trying to use and do here - which you completely fail to properly deal with. How intelligent is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vector<some_struct&> array` is invalid, period.

The type (or types) with which you instantiate a Standard Library container must be object types.  A reference type (like `some_struct&`) is not an object type.

By definition, "containers are objects that store other objects" (from §23.1/1 in both C++03 and C++0x).  References are not objects.

The behavior is undefined if you instantiate a container with a type that does not meet the requirements that the container imposes:  your code may or may not compile and if it does compile, who knows what the result will be; anything could happen..

Comment: It amazes me that 3 answers appeared before someone finally pointed out that the code _cannot_ work.

Comment: Just for clarity, in *the particular case* at hand there is no question of the compiling: one cannot have a raw array of references, one cannot have a pointer to reference.

Comment: @Alf:  Well, an implementation might specialize `std::vector` for reference-type `T`'s so that it would compile.  This would be a valid manifestation of undefined behavior.  This would also be quite silly and I don't know why anyone would ever do this.

Comment: @James: think about it. a vector must support `operator[]`, which must return reference to element. you can't form a reference to reference. the only two ways a compiler can support `vector<T&>` are (1) by giving it a novel non-standard meaning, such as `vector<T>`, or (2) by changing the semantics of references, and perhaps other language features. but that's when the compiler is made by leprechauns...

Comment: @Alf:  I don't disagree with you.  I'm just saying that if an implementation was to specialize `std::vector<T>` to transform `T& -> T` it would be standards conforming.  This would be silly and no implementation is going to do this.  Except, as you say, perhaps leprechauns.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

How does this even compile? That's not legal C++ code on any compiler I've used in the past 5 years.

Answer (score 2):

The vector reference says that push_back copies the data to the container. In your example, not the pointer to, but the contents of each structure would be copied. So if you use *new my_struct, the reference to the memory allocated for the structs will be lost after having used them to pass the data to the container, meaning you need to store those pointers to each of the structs you allocated somewhere to be able to release them, or you will get memory leaks.

If you wanted to keep the pointers, the container should be a `vector<some_struct*>`, and you could pass `new some_struct` and should (e.g.) release them with `delete array [i]`.

Answer (score 0):

If your vector is declared `vector<some_struct&> array`, `array.push_back(new some_struct)` shouldn't work. `array.push_back(some_struct())` will work and in that case you don't need to call delete.

Comment: sorry, edited that part, i meant `array.push_back(*new some_struct)`

Comment: is there a reason you're doing `"*new some_struct"` instead of `"some_struct()"`?

Comment: You cannot bind a `type&` to a temporary. VC++ will let you do it, but it will issue a non-conformance error. Also, it's a _really bad idea_. Never do this.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, that true. I never do this. Writing code without compiling it is bad.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to lose the memory allocated every time you do this.  You're essentially creating a copy of that data, but the original is lost in memory somewhere once this process completes.  Either keep an external reference to it somewhere which you can delete after you copy it, or use a vector of pointers, not references.